# What language does this grammar represent?

Tags: context-free-grammar

I believe it is a language that starts with an `a` and ends with a `b`, but I'm not sure.

```
G = (V,∑,P,S) where V={A,B,S,T}, ∑={a,b},  
P = { S → ε | T | AB, T → aTb | ε, A → aA | Aaa | ε, B → bB | ε }
```

Comment: Please don't post an image of text when you could just actually type the text.

Comment: I wouldn't know how to type all of those things... too many special characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the start. For the first substitution, there are three possibilities. If it's `S -> ε`, you're finished. So the language contains the empty word `ε`. If the first substitution is `S -> T`, what can happen with `T`? Simple, `T` can become either `ε` or `aTb`, no other nonterminals can ever become involved, so that production produces the sublanguage (I'll leave that for you to work out, it's homework). Finally, what if the first substitution is `S -> AB`? Looking at the productions starting with `A` resp. `B`, the right hand sides con only ever contain one nonterminal, the one you started with and substituting `A` may add one or two `a`, substituting `B` either ends (`ε`) or adds another `b`. So which combinations of `a` and `b` are reachable? Does `ba` belong to the language? Why resp. why not?

Hint: `S -> AB -> Aε = A -> aA -> aε = a` is valid, so a nonempty word need not end with `b`.